# How to calculate total minutes before end of day?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

Let say in my DB table I've the following records

[image]

Now how can I get the total minutes that student 9652 spent on **2016-08-24 00:00:01** till **2016-08-24 23:59:59** ? The query I tried

```
SELECT Sum(Timestampdiff(minute, start, end_date)) AS shift_mins FROM  


 `student_shift_history` WHERE  student_id = 9652 


AND `start` BETWEEN '2016-08-24 00:00:01' AND '2016-08-24 23:59:59'
```

Above query gives the total minutes sum of next day also.

What I need is total minutes that student 9652 spent on **2016-08-24**. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're considering the `end_date` for every row. You need to check whether the `end_date` is greater than the end date of the date you are checking.

I can not try it at the moment, but pseudo-working mysql could look like this:

```
SELECT Sum(
   Timestampdiff(minute, start, LEAST(end_date, '2016-08-24 23:59:59'))
) AS shift_mins 
FROM 
    `student_shift_history` 
WHERE  student_id = 9652 
AND `start` BETWEEN '2016-08-24 00:00:01' AND '2016-08-24 23:59:59'
```

The query is supposed to say:

> Take all the records where the start date is in range and then for all those, sum up the number of minutes between the start time and either the `end_date` or the end of the day I'm interested in if that's before `end_date`.

---

The question how to add the remaining minutes for the next day has a similar solution.

First of all, you need to make sure that `start` is treated in a smiliar way when calculating the minutes:

```
SELECT Sum(
   Timestampdiff(
       minute, 
       GREATEST(start, '2016-08-24 00:00:00'), 
       LEAST(end_date, '2016-08-24 23:59:59')
   )
) AS shift_mins
```

Similar to the last change, this does the following:

- If `start` is the previous day, count only from the start of the day you're interested in
- If `start` is some time of the day you're interested in, everything is like it was before

Now you also need to adjust your `WHERE` clause to make sure that you get all kinds of records you want. These are

- Records where both `start` and `end_date` are within the day you're interested in
- Records where `start` is before the day you're interested in and `end_date` is after that day
- Records where `start` is before the day you're interested in and `end_date` is within that day
- Records where `start` is within the day and `end_date` is after

The condition for that is surprisingly simple:

```
WHERE
    start < `2016-08-24 23:59:59` AND end_date > `2016-08-24 00:00:00`
```

So the entire statement should look like this:

```
SELECT Sum(
   Timestampdiff(
       minute, 
       GREATEST(start, '2016-08-24 00:00:00'), 
       LEAST(end_date, '2016-08-24 23:59:59')
   )
) AS shift_mins 
FROM 
    `student_shift_history` 
WHERE  
    student_id = 9652 AND
    start < `2016-08-24 23:59:59` AND 
    end_date > `2016-08-24 00:00:00`
```

That should work. If it does not, you still get the picture :-)

Comment: thanks man, it worked great, but it raise another question, Now how can I check the remaining minutes next day?

Comment: Then you have to change your where condition. I'm going to change my answer.

Comment: if you could give a query, covering both scenarios it would much appreciated.